# Visual studio 2010 email activity for workflow

Tags: development, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2010(sequential sharepoint work flow) and trying to send an email  activity automatically when the approval is rejected. I have added the "send email" activity in the workflow design. Can some body please tell me what has to be added to code. I would appreciate a detailed explanation as I am doing this for the first time. The workflow will be added to sharepoint.

Comment: This question is probably off-topic for StackOverflow, but would be very welcome on the SharePoint.StackExchange.com site.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't run into this issue:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/73927fb1-2754-4bc2-9695-7dda77de576c/

And use the following as reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowactions.sendemail_methods(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 1):

When using the Send Email Activity you can set the subject, body, sendto etc.. in the property window or by settings this in code.

A good start building workflows in SharePointyou can read [Workflow Technical Articles for SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh352747.aspx) or [step by stem tutorial creating workflows for SharePoint](http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2011/01/06/step-by-step-tutorial-creating-workflows-for-sharepoint-2010-step-115/)